# Randomly flipping a coin

Tags: python-3.x

I need to write a function called flip_coins(n) that returns the amount of heads. Then I need to to write a program that flips 8 coins a thousand times and returns the amount of times heads comes up three times in a row with a loop. After that I have some calculations on probability of the flips. So far this is what I have, but it wont run. What am I missing?

```
import random

def flip_coin():
    return random.choice("HT")


def flip_coins(n):
    for i in range(n):
        if flip_coins() == "H":
            heads_count +=1

        return heads_count


for i in range (1000):
    if flip_coins(8) == "3":
        multiple_heads_count += 1

    return multiple_heads_count


print(multiple_heads_probability)
print(second_probability)


multiple_heads_probability = multiple_heads_count/1000
second_probability = 56/256
```

Comment: to improve the time performance (for larger cases), you could [flip many coins at once e.g., using the result of `random.getrandbits(nflips)`](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/433050/23044)

Answer (score 1):

This is rather interesting, similar to a dice rolling program I wrote a few months ago to get me back into python!

The first thing I noticed is that the code is trying to print two variables before they are created, you also need to be careful when dividing an integer, it will always return an integer, this meant that without converting to a float first (using `float()` or adding `.0` to the end of an integer) the result will always be zero. So I changed those lines to:

```
multiple_heads_probability = float(multiple_heads_count)/1000
second_probability = 56.0/256

print(multiple_heads_probability)
print(second_probability)
```

Secondly, if you want the program to find the probability of throwing a heads three times **in a row**, then I would suggest adding an `else` statement after your `if flip_coin() == "H":` block. Then another `if` statement to determine whether there have been 3 in a row. Also, in order to add to a variable, you must first **initialize** them, you can do this using: `heads_count = 0` and adding to it later. So I changed your second function to:

```
def flip_coins(n):
    heads_count = 0
    heads_rows = 0
    for i in range(n):
        if flip_coin() == "H":
            heads_count +=1
        else:
            heads_count == 0

        if heads_count == 3:
            heads_rows += 1
            heads_count = 0
        else:
            pass
    return heads_rows
```

Lastly, the `for` loop. Why are you using `return` outside of a function? This is only for use when writing a fruitful (not void) function and not in loops (unless inside a fruitful function). In the line `if flip_coins(8) == "3":`, you are comparing an integer to a string so it will always return false. Because of the changes to `flip_coins()` I have also changed the `for` loop in other ways, it is now:

```
multiple_heads_count = 0
for i in range (1000):
    if flip_coins(8) >= 1: #if there were any occurrences of 3 heads (H) in a row
        multiple_heads_count += 1
```

The corrected and complete code is below, along with 10 possible outputs (out of thousands).

Code:

```
import random

def flip_coin():
    return random.choice("HT")

def flip_coins(n):
    # initialize two variables for incrementation
    heads_count = 0
    heads_rows = 0
    for i in range(n): # do n times
        if flip_coin() == "H": # if flipped a heads
            heads_count +=1 # increment heads_count by one
        else: # otherwise
            heads_count == 0 # reset heads_count

        if heads_count == 3: # if there have been three heads so far
            heads_rows += 1 # increment heads_rows by one
            heads_count = 0 # reset heads_count
        else: # otherwise
            pass # do nothing
    return heads_rows

multiple_heads_count = 0 # initialize a variable for incrementation
for i in range (1000): # do 1000 times
    if flip_coins(8) >= 1: # if there was at least one three heads in a row
        multiple_heads_count += 1 # increment multiple_heads_count by one

multiple_heads_probability = float(multiple_heads_count)/1000 # calculate the probability of having at least one heads in a row
second_probability = 56.0/256 # This is the supposed theoretical probability, however I have not checked this yet

print(multiple_heads_probability)
print(second_probability)
```

Outputs:

```
0.865
0.21875

0.851
0.21875

0.853
0.21875

0.861
0.21875

0.866
0.21875

0.89
0.21875

0.839
0.21875

0.856
0.21875

0.855
0.21875

0.841
0.21875
```

I am intrigued as to what `56.0/256` represents, could someone enlighten me in a comment?

Comment: Still working on the math, but pretty sure 56/256 is the expected answer.

Comment: @gariepy Ok, I will have a look at that as it seems that the theoretical probability should be closer to what is here the experimental probability.

Comment: I have edited the answer to include commented code and explain what 56/256 is for.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are calling "flip_coins" from inside itself.  You want to call "flip_coin" from inside "flip_coins" like this:

```
def flip_coins(n):
    for i in range(n):
        if flip_coin() == "H":  ## changed to flip_coin
            heads_count +=1

        return heads_count
```

EDIT:  There are several more issues here.

1. Variables must be assigned (i.e. appear on the left-hand side of an = sign) before they are referenced (appear in an expression to be evaluated).  This occurs in the function "flip_coins" where you need to assign heads_count=0 before you start you loop.  Also multiple_heads_count is never initialized before you try to increment it in the main (the code not inside a function definition).  Finally, you are trying to print two variables, multiple_heads_probability and second_probability before you ever assign them.
2. You are incorrectly trying to compare an integer with a string in your loop

   ```
   for i in range (1000):
       if flip_coin(8) == "3":  ## changed to flip_coin()
           multiple_heads_count += 1
   ```

   The value of flip_coin(8) is an integer, but you are checking for equality with the string "3".  Strings and integers are never equal.  In this case, just remove the quotes from around the 3.
3. You have a return statement outside of a function

   ```
   return multiple_heads_count
   ```

   This statement can be deleted.  After running the loop, the value of multiple_heads_count will still be available, because you are still in the same scope, so you can just print it out or use it however you need.
4. (**EDIT: NOTE** - this paragraph applies to Python 2.x, but not Python 3.x) Once you fix those syntax errors, you're going to find that your results always print "0".  That's because in python, division of two integers produces an integer result (the quotient, with the remainder thrown away).  In this case, you're always dividing an integer by a larger integer, so the quotient is always zero.  What you want is to divide the integers and get a floating point result, so you can force python to do this by specifying at least one element of the quotient as a floating point:

   ```
   multiple_heads_probability = multiple_heads_count/1000.0 ## added ".0"
   ```

   You can add ".0" to any integer value, and it will force floating point division.  This is a very important feature of python to be aware of.
5. Finally, based on your problem statement, your logic is wrong.  Your problem states that you should count instances of "three heads in a row" out of 8 coin flips, but your code counts ALL heads out of the 8, and returns the total number of heads.  Now, there is some ambiguity here.  You are checking for EXACTLY three heads, but is that what the problem states?  Even if you fix the logic to look for consecutive heads, you will ignore "HHHH", "HHHHH", etc. because you are testing for exactly three.  Also, are you supposed to count "HHHTTHHH" as two instances of three heads in a row?

Python is a great language, and it is a great choice for this kind of problem.  Good luck!

Comment: I changed that and it still didn't work any other ideas?

Comment: So I did try running this code, and there are quite a few issues here.  I will attempt to explain them.  I'm not going to write this code for you, because that's not what we try to do on stack overflow.  We try to teach so you can become a great programmer and answer questions yourself!  I will update my previous answer with more information.

Comment: Poster is using Python 3. Division in Python 3 is floating point by default.

Comment: @Tom Zych: Good catch.  I have updated my original answer with this caveat.

Comment: Thank You, for all the helpful info on the program!